# Ordering Select 2 Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am currently using the the following plugin and I'm trying to figure out how I can tell it to just display normally my options by the value not the text.

http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Anyone know?

```
<select id="status_id" class="width100p select2-offscreen" name="status_id" required="required" tabindex="-1" title="User Status">
    <option value="default">Please Select</option>
    <option value="1">Active</option>
    <option value="4">Banned</option>
    <option value="2">Inactive</option>
    <option value="3">Suspended</option>
</select>

$("#status_id, #role_id").select2({
    minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
    placeholderOption: 'first'
});
```

Comment: Either use a custom template or replace the textContents with values before calling the `select2` method.

Comment: I don't understand why that's the default behavior to sort by the text when all I did in my html is use php to loop over my array.

Comment: Select2 is not sorting by the text; It displays the options in the order they appear in the HTML. You should change your PHP code to generate the options in the order you want.